# Call back issue in twitter4j android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j library to post on twitter from android app. I have followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499935/android-twitter-integration-using-oauth-and-twitter4j). I am having one issue it displays login screen, but after entering username and password, it's displaying this screen.

[image]

I tried to display on sign in 4-5 times, but still it's displaying me this screen and not going back to my app again.

`Manifest` File

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.objectlounge.OBLTwitter.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="OBLTwitter"
                android:scheme="app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: see i have update question with manifest code.

Comment: have you defined callback url when creating the app in twitter dev site?

Comment: also remove this `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` and try!

Comment: Actually I am doing that by code.      requestToken = twitter
       .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);

Comment: No you have to put callback url on the app created over web!

Comment: I thought this app://OBLTwitter should work. But when I tried to add this but it says invalid url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54981/discussion-between-muhammad-babar-and-keen).

Comment: Please guide me how to give call back url from dev.twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something wrong with api key and api secret. I regenerated both and it started working.