# Twitter4j Call back issue - opening callback activity in browser

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j, android-twitter

I am integrating twitter posting in my app using `twitter4j` library. I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499935/android-twitter-integration-using-oauth-and-twitter4j). But I am having issue in call back. After authorizing it doesn't actually comes to our app, but actually it opens up call back activity that we specified in browser. I am not sure why this is happening.

I tried to search but couldn't find anything related to this. So May be people haven't noticed or I missed something while integrating it.

Either way please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: _I am following this_ -- There is no link here. Are you using a `WebView`? Did you setup a `WebViewClient` with `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` so that redirections are handled by the `WebView` itself (i.e. `view.loadUrl(url)`)?

Comment: @matiash  have added a link please see it again. No, I am not using WebView.

Answer (score 1):

It's opening the custom URL link inside the browser itself because you haven't defined which activity should handle the custom links Or You haven't defined proper categories. Here is a sample. Make sure you include the categories. The `android.intent.category.BROWSABLE` will ensure that the browser opens your app.

```
    private final String CALLBACKURL = "x-oauthflow-twitter://privlyT4JCallback";

    <activity
        android:name=".TwitterLinkGrabberService"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="privlyT4JCallback"
                android:scheme="x-oauthflow-twitter" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

you already install app with same callback, you must change the callback String from manifest and
call back constant from activity.try to use unique call back Address.

```
<data android:scheme="login-twitter" android:host="callback1" />
```

and

```
 static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "login-twitter://callback1";
```

Comment: I am doing this. Problem is it opens up this activity in browser itself.

Comment: if twitter app not install activity will send intent to browser because it is mention in intent filter.<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="t4jsample"
                    android:scheme="oauth" />

            </intent-filter>

Comment: use android:launchMode="singleInstance" and handle in code by this way  @Override
 protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
 {
  super.onNewIntent(intent);
  Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
   if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK_URL)) {
    String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(IEXTRA_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
            new RetrieveAccessTokenTask().execute(verifier);
         } 
 
      

 }

Comment: I can not have singleInstance for this activity for some other reasons.

Comment: make a new A activity without GUI and start activity for result from current activity.make A singleinstance and get require data and set result.now you can receive data on current activity.May it lengthy but solve your problem.user not feel what are done.sorry for poor english

Comment: use this sdk https://github.com/grantland/twitter-android-sdk/tree/master/twitter/src/me/grantland/twitter