# Steps for successfully login in twitter, in an android application

Tags: android, twitter, uri, twitter4j

I am trying to write a Sign In twitter screen android application. I am having trouble to understand the way URI works.

- What kind of data does it takes?
- What does `uri.toString().startsWith("mycallback_URL")` represents?
- What for is `String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier")` used ?

  ```
  public void TwitterLogin() 
  {
      Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
      if(uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith("mycallback_URL")) 
      {
          String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
          new TwitterTasks.TwitterGetAccessTokenTask(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this).execute(verifier);
      }
  }
  ```

`TwitterTasks` is another class containing an inner class `TwitterGetAccessTokenTask`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17501704/1239966

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way of using Twitter APIs than the one you are using now. Sign in and create your App [on twitter developer console](https://dev.twitter.com/), get the consumer key and secret. Download Temboo library [here](https://temboo.com/library/Library/Twitter/OAuth/).
Follow the Choreo example and instructions to make your task easier.